# Dropdown list taking duplicate value

Tags: html

```html
<label>Service Offering</label></br>
              <select  style='color:black' id="first_choice" required name="first_pref">
              <option value="" disabled selected hidden>First preference</option>
                    <option value="Engineering and Design">Engineering and Design</option>
              <option value="Operations and Design">Operations and Design</option>
              <option value="Product management">Product management</option>
              <option value="Developer relations and technical solutions">Developer relations and technical solutions</option>
              <option value="Sales and account management">Sales and account management</option>
              <option value="Partnerships">Partnerships</option>
              <option value="Sales and operations">Sales and operations</option>
                 <option value="Administrative services">Administrative services</option>
                  <option value="Business strategy planning">Business strategy planning</option>
              <option value="Finance solutions">Finance solutions</option>
              <option value="Legal and government relations">Legal and government relations</option>
              <option value="Marketing and communications">Marketing and communications</option>
              <option value="Real estate and workplace services">Real estate and workplace services</option>
              <option value="Social impact solutions">Social impact solutions</option>
              <option value="Consultancy services">Consultancy services</option>
              <option value="Investors and funding">Investors and funding</option>
            </select></br></br>
        <!--second preference-->
        <select  style='color:black' id="second_choice" required name="second_pref">
             
               <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Second Preference</option>
              <option value="Engineering and Design">Engineering and Design</option>
              <option value="Operations and Design">Operations and Design</option>
              <option value="Product management">Product management</option>
              <option value="Developer relations and technical solutions">Developer relations and technical solutions</option>
              <option value="Sales and account management">Sales and account management</option>
              <option value="Partnerships">Partnerships</option>
              <option value="Sales and operations">Sales and operations</option>
                 <option value="Administrative services">Administrative services</option>
                  <option value="Business strategy planning">Business strategy planning</option>
              <option value="Finance solutions">Finance solutions</option>
              <option value="Legal and government relations">Legal and government relations</option>
              <option value="Marketing and communications">Marketing and communications</option>
              <option value="Real estate and workplace services">Real estate and workplace services</option>
              <option value="Social impact solutions">Social impact solutions</option>
              <option value="Consultancy services">Consultancy services</option>
              <option value="Investors and funding">Investors and funding</option>
            </select></br></br>
   <!--3rd preference-->
        <select style='color:black' id="third_choice" required name="third_pref">
              <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Third Preference</option>
              <option value="Engineering and Design">Engineering and Design</option>
              <option value="Operations and Design">Operations and Design</option>
              <option value="Product management">Product management</option>
              <option value="Developer relations and technical solutions">Developer relations and technical solutions</option>
              <option value="Sales and account management">Sales and account management</option>
              <option value="Partnerships">Partnerships</option>
              <option value="Sales and operations">Sales and operations</option>
                 <option value="Administrative services">Administrative services</option>
                  <option value="Business strategy planning">Business strategy planning</option>
              <option value="Finance solutions">Finance solutions</option>
              <option value="Legal and government relations">Legal and government relations</option>
              <option value="Marketing and communications">Marketing and communications</option>
              <option value="Real estate and workplace services">Real estate and workplace services</option>
              <option value="Social impact solutions">Social impact solutions</option>
              <option value="Consultancy services">Consultancy services</option>
              <option value="Investors and funding">Investors and funding</option>
            </select>
```

I have three drop down lists all containing same data but different names.I want all the three lists to be selected with unique values.That means if 1 is selected in 1st list then 1 becomes unavailable for the rest two lists.How to implement this in a simple HTML form.

Comment: You can't do that using just HTML. You'd need to use Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably need to implement this with Javascript, with some function bound to the onClick of a submission. Here's a demo:

```js
function checkChoice() {
  // Get choices and put into an array
  var box1 = document.getElementById("first_choice");
  var box2 = document.getElementById("second_choice");
  var box3 = document.getElementById("third_choice");
  var choices = [
    box1.options[box1.selectedIndex].value,
    box2.options[box2.selectedIndex].value,
    box3.options[box3.selectedIndex].value
  ];
  var valuesSoFar = Object.create(null);
  for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; ++i) {
    var value = choices[i];
    if (value in valuesSoFar) {
      console.log("Found a duplicate");
      return false; // We found a duplicate, return false to stop form processing
    }
    valuesSoFar[value] = true;
  }
  console.log("No duplicates found");
  return true; // Everything is fine, continue 
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="#">
  <label>Services Offered</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <select style='color:black' id="first_choice" required name="first_pref">
    <option value="firstp" disabled selected hidden>First Preference</option>
    <option value="Engineering and Design">Engineering and Design</option>
    <option value="Operations and Design">Operations and Design</option>
    <option value="Product management">Product management</option>
    <option value="Developer relations and technical solutions">Developer relations and technical solutions</option>
    <option value="Sales and account management">Sales and account management</option>
    <option value="Partnerships">Partnerships</option>
    <option value="Sales and operations">Sales and operations</option>
    <option value="Administrative services">Administrative services</option>
    <option value="Business strategy planning">Business strategy planning</option>
    <option value="Finance solutions">Finance solutions</option>
    <option value="Legal and government relations">Legal and government relations</option>
    <option value="Marketing and communications">Marketing and communications</option>
    <option value="Real estate and workplace services">Real estate and workplace services</option>
    <option value="Social impact solutions">Social impact solutions</option>
    <option value="Consultancy services">Consultancy services</option>
    <option value="Investors and funding">Investors and funding</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>
  <select style='color:black' id="second_choice" required name="second_pref">
    <option value="secondp" disabled selected hidden>Second Preference</option>
    <option value="Engineering and Design">Engineering and Design</option>
    <option value="Operations and Design">Operations and Design</option>
    <option value="Product management">Product management</option>
    <option value="Developer relations and technical solutions">Developer relations and technical solutions</option>
    <option value="Sales and account management">Sales and account management</option>
    <option value="Partnerships">Partnerships</option>
    <option value="Sales and operations">Sales and operations</option>
    <option value="Administrative services">Administrative services</option>
    <option value="Business strategy planning">Business strategy planning</option>
    <option value="Finance solutions">Finance solutions</option>
    <option value="Legal and government relations">Legal and government relations</option>
    <option value="Marketing and communications">Marketing and communications</option>
    <option value="Real estate and workplace services">Real estate and workplace services</option>
    <option value="Social impact solutions">Social impact solutions</option>
    <option value="Consultancy services">Consultancy services</option>
    <option value="Investors and funding">Investors and funding</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>
  <select style='color:black' id="third_choice" required name="third_pref">
    <option value="thirdp" disabled selected hidden>Third Preference</option>
    <option value="Engineering and Design">Engineering and Design</option>
    <option value="Operations and Design">Operations and Design</option>
    <option value="Product management">Product management</option>
    <option value="Developer relations and technical solutions">Developer relations and technical solutions</option>
    <option value="Sales and account management">Sales and account management</option>
    <option value="Partnerships">Partnerships</option>
    <option value="Sales and operations">Sales and operations</option>
    <option value="Administrative services">Administrative services</option>
    <option value="Business strategy planning">Business strategy planning</option>
    <option value="Finance solutions">Finance solutions</option>
    <option value="Legal and government relations">Legal and government relations</option>
    <option value="Marketing and communications">Marketing and communications</option>
    <option value="Real estate and workplace services">Real estate and workplace services</option>
    <option value="Social impact solutions">Social impact solutions</option>
    <option value="Consultancy services">Consultancy services</option>
    <option value="Investors and funding">Investors and funding</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" onClick="checkChoice()">
</form>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

The snippet basically takes the three values of the select boxes, puts them into an array, and then loops through the array to see if any of the values are the same. If they are, we stop and return `false` to stop the form processing, and if none are found we return `true` to let the form continue.

Comment: i am not able to implement it since my form contains more data also not only this three lists.....